# Border size changes after re-opening LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice

I am using LibreOffice Calc, and I trying to set borders of a cell. When I do the following:

- Change Cell borders to 1pt
- Save the workbook
- Close the workbook
- Re-Open the workbook

The border size changes from 1pt to 2.50pt, what is causing this to happen?

Answer (score 1):

I found those two bugs on Bugzilla: ["LO 3.6 and 4.0 render cell borders thicker than in 3.4"](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60607) and ["FILEOPEN particular .xlsx shows cell border lines with wrong FORMATTING (too thick)"](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=56960).

They might be related to your issue.

It looks like this is fixed in the latest stable branch, LibreOffice 4.1.
You can update your version from [there](https://www.libreoffice.org/download) and give it another go.

Also, if you have more questions about LibreOffice, you might want to ask them on [ask.libreoffice.org](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/questions/) to centralise the information.